# How to test a custom Zend_Form with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-form, phpunit

Does anyone have an example of how to test a custom Zend_Form that extend from that class with PHPUnit?? I may need to test the construct and the init... where i'm adding elements to the My_Custom_Zend_Form.

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent screencast at zendcasts.com called [Unit Testing Zend_Form](http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-zend_form/2010/10/). Could it be of any help?